# Refactor if-else php code, again

Tags: php

Any ideas to refactor this?

```
if (is_dir($uploadDir.'temp'))
{
    === a ===
}
else
{
    if (!mkdir($uploadDir.'temp', 0755))
    {
        === b ===
    }
    else
    {
        === a ===
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: "Literally" literally doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: @meager: yes, my head literally exploded when I read that bit :-)

Comment: lol. What "head" are you guys thinking about?

Comment: @Victor Even if you take "literally" out, the resulting sentence doesn't make sense. What do you mean, get your "head out"?

Comment: @meagar, just an expression. Alright, removed it. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$dir = $uploadDir . 'temp';
if ( is_dir($dir) || mkdir($dir, 0755) ) {
    // === a ===
} else {
    // === b ===
}
```

Comment: If the `is_dir($dir)` already exists, then we `mkdir($dir, 0755)` again, will it return error?

Comment: If `is_dir()` returns `true`, then the `mkdir` call will not be evaluated, thanks to [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).